# jenkins + sonar + github integration without auth token

Tags: jenkins, github, sonarqube, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

We are setting up jenkins + sonar + github integration for automatic pullrequest static code check through sonar.

In jenkins post-build action we have the following properties:

```
-Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec
-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview
-Dsonar.github.repository=gitrepo
-Dsonar.host.url=sonar URL 
-Dsonar.login=sonar Username  
-Dsonar.password=sonar password
-Dsonar.github.oauth= PAT who has write permission to gitHub
-Dsonar.github.pullRequest=${ghprbPullId}
-Dsonar.github.disableInlineComments=false
-Dsonar.github.endpoint=company gitHub endpoint
```

For security reason, we don't want to use the token for parameter
    -Dsonar.github.oauth

If we don't provide auth token, sonar analysis report not updated in gitHub as comment.

Is there any other way to update sonar analysis report as comment in gitHub without using auth token.